# Android Material - cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, androidx

I have a `component_category_view.xml` with a ChipGroup initialized inside a constraintLayout that has an id `categoryList`,
I'm running the following `CategoryView.kt` class to inflate it and update it with chips dynamically and i have it placed inside my activity.

```
class CategoryView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

init {
    inflateLayout()
}


private fun inflateLayout() {
    val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_category_view, this, true)
}
fun updateCategories(categories: List<Category>){
    categories.forEach {
        var chipText = "${it.title.capitalize()} (${it.amount})"
        val chip = Chip(this@CategoryView.context)
        chip.text = chipText
        chip.isCheckable = true
        chip.chipBackgroundColor = null

        categoryList.addView(chip)
    }
}


}
```

When I run however and my code reaches the part where it's calling updateCategories with a list of Categories, the following error comes up:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.company.project, PID: 8262
>           java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.project.common.ui.CategoryView cannot be cast to
>   com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup

the `component_category_view.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               android:orientation="vertical"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                               android:background="@drawable/layout_border_bottom">

<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/categoryList"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Material theme instead of appCompact to solve chip problem:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">

<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

**Updated**

The error occurred because you're adding chip to categoriesList but it's required a chip group like below example:

```
private fun createChip(name: String, index: Int){

val chip = Chip(chip_group.context)

chip.id = index

chip.text = name

chip.isClickable = true

chip.isCheckable = true

chip.isCheckedIconVisible = false

chip_group.addView(chip)

}
```

And

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

  for ((index, item) in categories.withIndex()){
createChip(item.name, index)} }
```

Comment: My manifest is already using material theme `            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: thanks for your help so far but categoryList is the name of my chip group, i've added the xml to my question so you can see it. so the only change in your answer is to set the context of the new chip (in my case) to categoryList.context, the same error occurs but in the line of creating the chip, setting it to just "context" makes the same error also occur but in the addition to chip group like in my question.

Comment: If I use (val chip = Chip(context)) it occurs on line 71 (the addition line)
If I use (val chip = Chip(categoryList.context)) it occurs on line 34 (the initialization line)

Comment: Well you use categoryList.context and which line is 34

Comment: Of course the line chip as View indicate chip is a CategoryView. Use just chip

Comment: I changed it and its the exact same issue, notice the error is occurring on line 34, it doesnt even reach the add.

Comment: Can you show your all imports of your categoryView class.

Comment: Other imports too because I think it's a logical error.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was caused by the `id` field within the `Chip` view.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_fragment_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

After changing the value of the `id` field, the error went away.